# Google Chart Background

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I have this 2 googlecharts in my program:

```html
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


  var matrix = [];
  for(var i=0; i<50; i++) {
  matrix[i] = new Array(2);
  }
  var j=0;
$.getJSON("x.json",function(data){
  $.each(data, function(key, val){
   matrix[j][0]=(val.y);
   matrix[j][1]=(val.z);
   j++;
  }); 
 });

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['a', 'b'],
  [matrix[0][0], matrix[0][1]],
  [matrix[1][0], matrix[1][1]],
  [matrix[2][0], matrix[2][1]],
  [matrix[3][0], matrix[3][1]],
  [matrix[4][0], matrix[4][1]]
]);
// Set chart options
      var options = {'title':'h',
                     'width':900,
                     'height':400,
      is3D: true,
      
      };

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  var matrix = [];
  for(var i=0; i<50; i++) {
  matrix[i] = new Array(2);
  }
  var j=0;
  
  
$.getJSON("x.json",function(data){
  $.each(data, function(key, val){
   matrix[j][0]=(val.y);
   matrix[j][1]=(val.z);
   j++;
  }); 
 });
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
        [matrix[0][0], matrix[0][1], "red"],
        [matrix[1][0], matrix[1][1], "yellow"],
        [matrix[2][0], matrix[2][1], "green"],
        [matrix[3][0], matrix[3][1], "grey"]
  
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);

      var options = {
        title: "k",
        width: 800,
        height: 300,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        legend: { position: "none" }
  
  

  
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
   <!--options-->
  }
  </script>
<div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 800px; display: inline-block;"></div>

  </div>
```

I want to change the background color of both.
I've tryed some of the solutions for background color change, like adding the background color to the options, adding a chart area and using the chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options)) method. 
But the chart simple disapears.
Any solution for this?

Comment: Hi, I got your example and I set `'backgroundColor': 'blue'` in option and its work...check this plz: http://jsfiddle.net/hwj1cy8p/ -- Maybe Your issue in mistake when write `backgroundColor` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change Google Chart Color By write in `backgroundColor` in your option, for example -by using your code-:

```
  var options = {
      'backgroundColor': 'blue',
  };

  var chart = new 
  google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

for your first snippet code, you can check this work color in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwj1cy8p/)

Comment: Ok. My mistake was that I was writing background-color instead of backgroundColor. Got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome mate :)